# web like expandable UI look in RadForm (Telerik )

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, telerik

Hi I need to show the user a web like UI. Most of the website have three lines in the right bottom corner to show user that the control is expandable.

I need to show the same in the windows form as shown in the picture

[image]

Is it possible in winforms to show there lines in the right bottom corner like this in WPF with telerik?

**I tried enabling SizrGripStyle to show  but it doesn't work in telerik radForm.It only works on winforms**

Answer (score 1):

You would have to set the form Property `SizeGripStyle` to `Show` in order for the grip lines to be shown. Please refer below.

[image: WinForms SizeGripStyle Property]

Once the above property is set to `Show` the re-size grip would be shown in the on right hand corner of the screen.

[image]

I'm on Windows 7 PC, so hope that the re -size grip is distinguishable in the above image.

Comment: @dahsra, or sorry my bad. I thought you were trying to achieve this with WinForms.

Comment: @dahsra, did some search and it seems that Telerik team is aware of such an feature and they have mentioned in some of the article found in [this search](http://www.telerik.com/search?start=0&q=size%2bgrip&collection=telerik30). Not sure whether Telerik have released the feature and this sure looks to be dependent on the version of Telerik you are making use of.

Comment: Also refer the API Reference documentation for [RadFormBehavior.ScrollbarSizingGripBounds Property](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/api/html/P_Telerik_WinControls_UI_RadFormBehavior_ScrollbarSizingGripBounds.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that currently there is an issue with this functionality: http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/154/Feedback/Details/151535

What you can do is to add an empty [RadStatusStrip](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/forms-and-dialogs/statusstrip/radstatusbar-properties) control and use its sizing grip